# Magento + M2ePro + Shipworks Template = XSLT Regular Expression Problems

Tags: regex, magento, xslt

I'm using magento(EE) Enterprise Edition 1.12 M2e Pro(M2), Channel Advisor (CA) and Shipworks(SW) 3.6.0.4651 *sigh*.

So here's the scenario. I'm sending inventory from EE to CA, from CA to Amazon, From Amazon to M2, From M2 to EE, From EE to SW.

I created a custom call in EE to grab the amazon order id from M2, then edited the SW php file to pass it as an attribute to SW.

I can see the amazon order Id as an option in SW, and am using this:

```
<xsl:variable name="option2" select="$order/Item/Option[Name='AmazonOrderId']" />
```

my output is something like this:

```
AmazonOrderId109-2691618-61642030AmazonOrderId
```

How would I go about getting the text "AmazonOrderId" out of the variable Option2 without messing up SW?

Comment: Here is the XML "raw data" from SW
        
    <Option ID="64345020">
    <Name>AmazonOrderId</Name>
    <Description>109-2691618-6164203</Description>
    <UnitPrice>0</UnitPrice>
    </Option>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your example input, `$option2` contains:

```
 AmazonOrderId 109-2691618-6164203 0
```

that is all the text nodes within the `<Option>` element. Note that the **Option ID** ("64345020") is not included. Assuming the **Order ID** here is "109-2691618-6164203", set the variable to:

```
"$order/Item/Option[Name='AmazonOrderId']/Description"
```

to grab (only) it. Can't say what will or won't "mess up SW".

Comment: I know it was going to be something simple like that. Thank you very much. I've been working on this off and on for the past few days!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't place the AmazonOrderId within [] it should be like this

```
select="$order/Item/Option/Description" />
```